# Count of values based on several criteria

Tags: excel

First of all I want to thank you all for even reading this and helping me out.
I have a problem that I can't solve and reading Excel tips and tricks did not help.

I have a table (below only with much more rows) where I have to get a unique count of how many times a person worked from home and how many times the/she went to the office. The result I'm looking for is:

[image: required result]

I have exhausted my wisdom and hope for your help.

[part1 of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPq2p.png)
[part2 of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YtWW.png)

TABLE:

```
PERSON NUMBER   PERSON NAME         DATE            REPORTED HOU    LOCATION
7272            John Doe            2021-03-01      3               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-01      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-01      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-01      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-02      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-02      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-02      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-03      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-03      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-03      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-03      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-03      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-04      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-04      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-04      3               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-04      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-04      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-05      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-05      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-05      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-05      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-05      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-08      3               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-08      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-08      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-08      2               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-09      3               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-10      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-10      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-10      1               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-10      5               WFH
7272            John Doe            2021-03-02      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-01      3               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-01      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-01      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-01      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-02      2               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-02      2               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-02      2               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-03      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-03      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-03      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-03      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-03      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-04      2               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-04      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-04      3               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-04      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-04      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-05      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-05      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-05      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-05      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-05      2               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-08      3               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-08      2               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-08      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-08      2               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-09      3               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-09      1               WFH
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-10      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-10      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-10      1               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-10      5               Office
7273            Jane Doe            2021-03-10      2               Office
```

Comment: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-countifs-function

Comment: I kept fixing your table and you kept changing it.  roll it back to my last fix and the table will be formatted correctly.

Comment: Sorry man, but the table was horrible so i created a screenshot.

Comment: WE prefer table that can be copied pasted not photos.

Comment: @sous2817 thank you very much, but I have 500+ names. So what I want to do is first have the list of those names (that can change on daily/weekly/monthly  basis) and then do the count

Comment: please see: [mcve]

Comment: @ScottCraner I pasted the table too

Answer (score 1):

You can count unique records with SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIF with multiple criteria:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/07/how-to-count-distinct-and-unique-values-in-excel/

I got this:

[image]

My formula in H5 is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$75;$B$2:$B$75;$C$2:$C$75;$C$2:$C$75;$E$2:$E$75;$E$2:$E$75;$B$2:$B$75;$G5;$E$2:$E$75;H$4);0))
```

As you can see, it returns the exptected output (notice my headers are WFH and Office)

Comment: Sorry, just used yours to add making the names list...

Comment: @SolarMike no problem!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. My wife is exactly friendly with VBA or other solutions and "simple" formula is always best.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a VBA solution --

Add a reference (**Tools** -> **References...** from the VBA editor) to **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects** (the latest version; usually `6.1`).

Then, you can write code like the following:

```vb
Const filepath As String = "C:\path\to\excel\file.xlsx"
Const sheetname As String = "Sheet1"

Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filepath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""

    ' If your data is in a macro-enabled file (.xlsm), the previous line should
    ' look like this:
    ' "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No"""

Dim sql As String
sql = _
    "SELECT [PERSON NAME], COUNT(*) " & _
    "FROM [" & sheetname & "$] " & _
    "GROUP BY [PERSON NAME]"

' If your data is only part of the worksheet, you can specify the range as follows:
' sql = _
'    "SELECT [PERSON NAME], COUNT(*) " & _
'    "FROM [" & sheetname & "A1:E10000$] " & _
'    "GROUP BY [PERSON NAME]"

Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Worksheets.Add.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset(rs)
```

This code will add a new worksheet to the active workbook with the grouped data in it.

---

**References:**

Microsoft Access SQL (used when querying Excel files):

- [Access SQL: basic concepts, vocabulary, and syntax](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/access-sql-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444d0303-cde1-424e-9a74-e8dc3e460671#:%7E:text=Relational%20database%20programs%2C%20such%20as,such%20as%20ISO%20and%20ANSI.)
- [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-access-sql-reference)

ADODB:

- [**Recordset** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-ado) — [**Open** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/open-method-ado-connection)

Excel:

- [**Worksheets** collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets) — [**Add** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheets.add)
- [**Worksheet** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet) — [**Range** property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range)
- [**Range** object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)) — [**CopyFromRecordset** method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset)

Comment: Tested the solution and it works perfectly, but it is too complicated for me wife who is not exactly tech savy. 
Thank you anyway man!

Comment: @GregaKovac I've added some links/references to my answer; this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

This goes with the answer from Foxfire and Burns and Burns:

The unique list of names can be automatically produced using unique() as shown:

[image]

However, it can be built manually using a copy of the names and the "Remove Duplicates" button.